What is "boosted electrical level" in a USB?
I read through the USB2517's datasheet and I see one of its pins can be configured to use the USB ports at "boosted electrical level".

I could not find what "boosted electrical level" is. I can only assume it means high(er) voltage? Is this "boosted electrical level" a term used in USB protocol?

The "boosted electrical level" feature is called by MCHP/SMSC marketing as "PHYboost". It was invented to compensate for loss of signal levels due to extra components that a OEM can deploy to have a better ESD protection or combat FCC emission, which usually involves Common Mode Chokes (with certain DC impedance) and/or ESD diodes (with some extra capacitance). And for trace loss of course.
The feature allows customers to tune the hub output in such a way that the signal can have the USB-IF-certified eye diagram at the user-exposed ports. There is an application note on this.

10-15 years ago every USB product from SMSC/MCHP had an illustration of eye diagrams with different PHYboost settings on first pages of datasheets.
Today the programmable/tunable PHY output can be found in all major host controllers.

The link in the table to "Register F6h" gives some idea:

There are four settings, normal, +4%, +8% and +12% of the nominal drive strength.
This is not a USB standard compliant feature as noted. It appears to have been added for OEMs to use to cope with lossy channels (e.g. very long lines) by slightly increasing the signal strength above its normal standard conformant level.
